# angularjs post json to spring

Tags: json, angularjs, spring

400 Bad Request 
angular js json to spring mvc

i create login page module using angular js

it goto json format from angular to spring

how to receive the code is error while run 400 bad request

myjsp code:

```
  <div id="showProjects" ng-controller="crescentGetProjects">

    <table>

    <tr><td>User Name</td><td><input type="text" id="pname" name="pname" ng-model="project.UserName"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="text" id="aname" name="aname" ng-model="project.Password"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="hidden" ng-model="project.projectId" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="saveProjectDetails(project)"></td></tr>

    </table>
    </div>
```

my js code:

```
function crescentGetProjects($scope,$http){
    $scope.saveProjectDetails = function(project)
    {

            console.log(project);
            var dataObj = {
                    UserName : $scope.project.UserName,
                    Password : $scope.project.Password

            };
        var res=$http.post('research/api/register',dataObj);
        res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.message = data;
            alert("success");
        });
        res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("failure");


        });
```

controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody String registerUser(@RequestBody LoginEntity userModel,HttpServletRequest request) {
    String resp=null;
    try{
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$ "+userModel.getUserName());
    crescentManager.LoginCheck(userModel);
    resp="success";
    }catch(Exception e){
        resp="fail";
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return resp;

}
```

my entity class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="LOGININFO")
public class LoginEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="LOGINID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer LoginId;

    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    private String UserName;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String Password;

    public Integer getLoginId() {
        return LoginId;
    }

    public void setLoginId(Integer loginId) {
        LoginId = loginId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {

        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@username is settled in entity   "+userName);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }


}
```

erroe msg
400 
bad request

Comment: Can you post the captured HTTP request from Firebug or Dev tools?

Comment: Also, it would be great if you provided the error log output provided by Spring

Comment: Try fallowing the convention of camel case variable name. JsonParser is expecting userName variable name for getUserName(), whereas your code is providing UserName. Hence, this 400 Bad Request Error.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "research/api/register" change like this

Comment: hi hurricane this error will show i change the request mapping value WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/LoginTest/rest/research/api/register] in DispatcherServlet with name 'login-model'

Comment: Can you add this post your servlet-context.xml

Comment: And your full error code pls.

Comment: In my experience, this means that 1) You don't have a JSON parser library in your classpath or 2) the data that is send to the Spring controller, does not match the @RequestBody object. In your case dataObj != LoginEntity.

Comment: in fire bug  
400 Bad Request
  39ms 
angular.js (line 8407)
HeadersPostResponseHTMLCookies
JSON
  
 
Password
 "jobs"
 
UserName
 "steve"
Source
{"UserName":"steve","Password":"jobs"}

Comment: i put json-simple-1.1.1 library any other library import? my entity is correct

Comment: Just to be sure of what Spring controller gets, could you show the result of `public @ResponseBody String registerUser(@RequestBody String userModel) { System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$ "+userModel); return "fail"; }

Comment: Did you configure Spring to use the json.simple lib? With <mvc:annotation-driven> Spring set up a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter (from converting from/to JSON) automatically if a Jackon library is present in the classpath.